# ¿Cómo incluir el valor de un string en la ruta de un atributo src?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de Asp.net y el problema que me encuentro es que en el código de mi vista necesito incluir el valor de un string en un atributo src para que me cargue una imagen diferente cada vez que recargo la página.

```
<table>
    @{
        for (int fila = 1; fila <= 4; fila++)
        {
            <tr>
                @{ 
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    string[] baraja = (string[])ViewData["baraja"];
                    for (int columna = 1; columna <= 10; columna++)
                    {
                        <td><img src="..\..\wwwroot\images\@baraja[rnd.Next(39)]" width="180" height="270"/></td>
                    }
                 }
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Lo que quiero es que en src me considere el valor del string baraja[rnd.Next(39)] que contiene el nombre del archivo de la imagen.
Además me pide que codifique la imagen en base64, pero no consigo hacerlo, me sale el error "no se pudo encontrar el archivo ....\wwwroot\images@baraja[rnd.Next(39)]" y la ruta está bien, ya lo he comprobado. Es como si considerara el nombre del string y no su valor.
Espero haberme explicado más o menos bien.

Comment: Trata probando con la ruta de esta manera image/@baraja[rnd.Next(39)]

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado, de la siguiente forma:

```
<img src="~/images/@img" alt="@img" width="180" height="270"/>
```